# Can I change text color in bar graphs based on the underlying bar color?

Tags: color, charts

My code:

```
numbers = {117, 128, 171, 189, 202, 260, 267, 339, 427, 1302};  
languages = {"Lahnda", "Japanese", "Russian", "Bengali",   
   "Portuguese", "Hindi", "Arabic", "English", "Spanish", "Chinese" };  
font = "Verdana";

BarChart[numbers,   
BaseStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> font, FontSize -> 13],  
ChartStyle -> 10, ImageSize -> 560, BarOrigin -> Left,   
ChartLabels ->   
Placed[{numbers, languages}, {{{0.5, 0.5}, {0.5, 0.5}}, {{1, 0.5}, {-0.2, 0.5}}}, # &],  
AxesLabel -> {"", "millions\nof speakers"}]
```

which produces the following plot:
[image]

The black text is hard or even impossible (e.g. first bar) to read on dark colors. Is there a way to automagically the text color for best readability?

For extra credit:
It seems I used the *pos* parameters for `Placed` wrong/horribly, since the left margin is a fraction of the word length. The documentation for `Placed` doesn't seem to say how to use *pos*. How can I get an equal left margin, independent of text length?

*using version 9.0.1*

Comment: How about panels?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
BarChart[numbers, BaseStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> font, FontSize -> 13], 
 ChartStyle -> 10, ImageSize -> 560, BarOrigin -> Left, 
 ChartLabels -> Placed[languages, After], 
 LabelingFunction -> (Placed[
  Style[#, If[Plus @@ ColorData[10, Last[#2]] < 1.5, White, Black]], Center] &), 
 AxesLabel -> {"", "millions\nof speakers"}]
```

[image: Out0]

---

An alternative placement of the numbers:

```
BarChart[numbers, BaseStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> font, FontSize -> 13], 
 ChartStyle -> 10, ImageSize -> 560, BarOrigin -> Left, 
 ChartLabels -> Placed[languages, After],
 LabelingFunction -> (Placed[
  Style[#, If[Plus @@ ColorData[10, Last[#2]] < 1.5, White, Black]], Left] &), 
 AxesLabel -> {"", "millions\nof speakers"}]
```

[image: Out]

```
BarChart[numbers, BaseStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> font, FontSize -> 13], 
 ChartStyle -> 10, ImageSize -> 560, BarOrigin -> Left, 
 ChartLabels -> Placed[languages, After],
 LabelingFunction -> (Placed[
     Style[#, If[Plus @@ ColorData[10, Last[#2]] < 1.5, White, Black]], 
       {0 + 2/3*Min[numbers]/#, 0.5}] &), 
 AxesLabel -> {"", "millions\nof speakers"}]
```

[image: Out2]

```
BarChart[numbers, BaseStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> font, FontSize -> 13], 
 ChartStyle -> 10, ImageSize -> 560, BarOrigin -> Left, 
 ChartLabels -> Placed[languages, After],
 LabelingFunction -> (Placed[
     Row[{Spacer[10], 
       Style[#, If[Plus @@ ColorData[10, Last[#2]] < 1.5, White, Black]]}], Left] &), 
 AxesLabel -> {"", "millions\nof speakers"}]
```

[image: Out3]

Comment: Your first solution is exactly what I wanted. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Yes. No worries, I do have the right code now, but maybe other readers might expect the same layout as in my question. Though it will be obvious to most readers you can always make a note that changing "Left" to "Center" would create that layout.

Comment: @stevenvh OK, I added it anyway, because I wanted to see how a different placement changes the impression.

Answer (score 4):

```
BarChart[numbers, 
 BaseStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> font, FontSize -> 13], 
 ChartStyle -> 10, ImageSize -> 560, BarOrigin -> Left, 
 ChartLabels -> Placed[{languages}, {{{1, 0.5}, {-0.2, 0.5}}}, # &], 
 AxesLabel -> {"", "millions\nof speakers"}, 
 LabelingFunction -> (Placed[Panel[#1, FrameMargins -> 0], Center] &)]
```

[image]